# How to reproduce Tomcat 9.0.0.M1 HTTP smuggling vulnerabilities?

Tags: proxy, nginx, tomcat, request-smuggling

I'm trying to reproduce some of the Tomcat 9.x.x vulnerabilities [from this list](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-9.html), in particular the HTTP smuggling vulnerabilities. However, so far I haven't been able to reproduce any of them. Currently I'm running Tomcat 9.0.0.M1 behind an nginx 1.22.0 reverse proxy on Ubuntu.

Can anyone here point me towards a resource that describes in more detail how to reproduce these vulnerabilities? Perhaps a specific version or configuration of nginx (or a different front-end reverse proxy) is necessary to reproduce them? So far, I've only found the same blurbs from the Tomcat advisory reposted on other sites, with no elaboration.

**Attempt to reproduce HTTP smuggling with trailer header:**

As mentioned above, I'm running Tomcat 9.x.x behind an nginx 1.22.0 reverse proxy. I have the proxy blocking all requests to `/manager/*` and `/host-manager/*` (it returns 404 for matching requests), and I'd like to try bypassing this block using HTTP request smuggling. If I'm able to view the login page for either manager portal (even without valid credentials), I would consider the exploit successful.

One of the smuggling exploits listed in the security advisory concerns trailer headers:

> Tomcat did not correctly parse HTTP trailer headers. A specially crafted trailer header that exceeded the header size limit could cause Tomcat to treat a single request as multiple requests leading to the possibility of request smuggling when behind a reverse proxy.

In `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`, I checked that `rejectIllegalHeader` was set to `false`. I also checked that the maximum HTTP header length parameter was set to `2048`.

Therefore, I crafted several `HTTP/1.1` requests to `/` with a trailer header called `X` with lengths of 2047, 2048 and 2049, but I observed no abnormal behavior (the home page was returned without errors, and subsequent requests appeared unaffected). I also tried tacking HTTP requests onto the end of this header, in the hopes that the header (and request) might be truncated after 2048 characters, causing this smuggled request to "split off". But I did not find any indication that this trailer headers was being parsed in a dangerous way.

Has anyone managed to reproduce this vulnerability before, or does anyone have more specific information about the circumstances in which is presents itself?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Show us the steps you took to try to exploit the vulns.

Comment: What are the security implications of accessing /manager/ or /host-manager/ endpoints? They are password-protected.

Comment: @AlexVelickiy From what I understand, they would be blocked just because there isn't generally any reason for the "outside world" to have access to them (so, least privilege). But for the sake of this question, /manager/ and /host-manager/ are fungible with any other path that we might want to block access to at the level of the reverse proxy.

Comment: Regarding your question. I think even the correct exploit won't work with nginx as it converts chunked bodies to plain (content-length) bodies and therefore strips trailer headers.

Comment: As @AlexVelickiy said chances are that the proxy you use is very important. You need a proxy that would not reformat your trailer headers. Apache and Nginx have removed support from trailers long time ago, you'll have to search for a very *weak* proxy, something like a new project stating 'how to write a simple reverse proxy in <here choose any cool language>'.